# How to create a map pin on a 3d object in c# unity?

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine, pins

I want to create a map pin. Sort of like a google map pin that will stay static to my 3d object as I rotate around my object.

right now, I am using a sprite but when I rotate around my 3d object, the sprite doesn't show on the other site, I only shows when I rotate my 3d object on the side that the sprite is on.

so what can I do to have my sprite stay static and see through the model when I rotate around it?

**Think of a google map pin functionality (but on a 3d object, not on a flat surface)**

PS. I also want to point out that I am viewing it in a 3D world, not 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a textured quad which faces the camera. In your scene add a 3d-Object>Quad and position it above your 3d object. Make a new material and assign the albedo your Map Pin texture, set rendering mode to transparent, fade, or cutout if you have alpha values less than 1 (i recommend fade). Assign this material to your quad by dragging the material onto the quad gameobject in the inspector. Add a script to your quad called `FaceCamera` (or whatever you like), this script will update the forward of the quad's transform to always face the camera. You should now be able to rotate around your 3d object and have the map pin appear above it while facing the camera.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FaceCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.forward = (transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position);
    }
}
```

edit: To have the map pin always appear through your 3d object you should create a shader using `create>shader>unlit shader` and edit it so that for tags you have `Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" }` and after `Pass` but before `CGPROGRAM` you add `ZTest Always` and `Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha`. You can also rename the shader something like `MapPinShader`. Assign this shader to your map pin material by going into the shader drop down `unlit>'name of shader'`.

```
Shader "Unlit/MapPinShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            ZTest Always
            ZWrite On
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            // make fog work
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                // apply fog
                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, I am looking at your answer and I don't want the sprite to be above my 3d object. I want it to be at the same spot as my 3d object, and when I rotate my camera, the sprite will always show. Imagine if the sprite was in the middle on a 3d object. By default in unity, you can't see it because it is engulfed by the 3d object. So how do I make the sprite show when it is inside of a 3d object, or anywhere on the 3d object when i rotate my camera?

Comment: also, the squad only works when it is in front of a flat surface, not in front of 3d object

Comment: @codingpanda The second part is how you get it to always show. By creating a new shader and adding the code I mention. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: no i didn't try the second part. I will do it and let you know. One more question, you said to put the quad above the 3d object. But why is it above it? My 3d object is a tower like structure. So I want to be able to place my pin anywhere within the 3d object. So like inside of my 3d object. So can I place my quad anywhere?

Comment: @codingpanda yes you can place it inside if you like, if you implement the shader properly it will show through the 3d object. I only said place it above because i was assuming you wanted a map pin above your object.